# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate keep throwing an error when trying to update a nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, findoneandupdate

This may well be me doing something wrong.
I'm trying to update a nested object, but I'm failing..... well sort of.

My Mongoose model looks a bit like this:

```
{
root_level_stuff: 
{
......
},
Vehicles: [
{
   other_fields: {
   ..........
   },
   Id: {
     type: Number
   },
   Recycle: {
     type: Boolean
   }]
}
```

I'm trying to update a record using the following:

```
let result = await vehicle_model.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: some_id, 'Vehicles.Id': some_other_id }, { 'Vehicles.Recycle': true });
```

The field Recycle may or may not be present. So if it's not, add it. If it is, update it.

But the it responds by returning a load of records (not just the one I'm wanting to update), and my app bombs with the error "PathNotViable'.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Not to be annoying, but some of the terminology here is confusing/misleading. When you say that it is returning a "_load o[f] records_" I'm interpreting that to mean that it is "_returning the full document, including all of the entries in the `Vehicles` array_". It would be helpful to have the full error message, but based on `"PathNotViable"` and the shape of your `findOneAndUpdate()`, I think you may be looking to use the positional operator/array filters: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/

Comment: Sorry. Yes you're quite right. I was in a bit of a hurry trying to get this posted. Yes, it does look like it returns the whole record set, when I say "load of" records. And you're spot on with the positional operator because using { 'Vehicles.$.Recycle': true } worked. If you want to post that as an answer I'll flag it as answering the original post. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, you can achieve what you want using the [positional `$` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) as follows:

```
db.collection.update({
  _id: 123,
  "Vehicles.Id": "A"
},
{
  $set: {
    "Vehicles.$.Recycle": true
  }
})
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/11ldlOb_moY).

If in the future you needed something a little bit more complex for your array manipulations, you could look into the following:

- [The filtered positional operator (`$[<identifier>]`)](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)
- [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) which would open up usage of operators such [$map](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) that provide even greater flexibility.